# How query two mysql tables and pull results that are not on both table and or meet condition specify

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have two tables

### user table

```
 user_id | name  |
    1    | peter |
    2    | kofi  |
    3    | sam   |
    4    | nasah |
    5    | sarah |
    6    | david |
    7    | dan   |
```

### time table

```
 time_id | user_id | register
    1    |     1   |  present
    2    |     2   |  absent
    3    |     3   |  absent
    4    |     4   |  present
    5    |     5   |  absent
```

in the "time" table under "register" column, user can iether register "present" or "absent" when they login into the system.

I want a mysql query that select users who have either register "absent" or has not register at all.

the return result should be

```
kofi  | absent
sam   | absent
sarah | absent
david | 
dan   |
```

Comment: I don't get it your relation between tables... user_id is a PK and user_id is a FK with different var type?

Comment: @jcho360 You're right, the keys and relationships aren't set up properly between these tables.  You can get the data the OP wants using his structure though, and you can also get it if you fix the tables (I've shown both ways in my answer)

Comment: please check my answer.. its working. Also provided link with test...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.register 
FROM time t1
RIGHT JOIN user t2
ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id
WHERE (t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)
```

### [Its working, tested here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c25ab/1).

---

### Update 1

Per you conversation, you want to further filter based on time/ date

***let say i want to find out those who where absent or did not enter the system before 06-13-12 assuming there is a column name "date" in the time table***

Use below query

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.register, t1.mydate 
FROM time t1
RIGHT JOIN user t2
ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id
WHERE 
     (t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)
     AND
     (t1.mydate <= '2012-06-13' OR t1.mydate is null)
```

### [Here is demo for new requirement](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15203/3)

---

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: sorry, i have restructured my question. i made a mistake in my second table, it was actually the users id from table 1. thank you for your swift responds.

Comment: +1, after looking at your answer I realized I misunderstood OP's question (the query I gave did work though).  Anyway deleted my answer but maybe you could add the part I had about fixing the `user_id` column in `time`? I think that concept would be good for the OP to learn.

Comment: i tried your answer, it worked perfectly. thanks. i however have a follow up question. how about if i want to filter the final result again by date. let say i want to find out those who where absent or did not enter the system before 06-13-12 assuming there is a column name "date" in the time table

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT t1.name,t2.register from user t1 
left join time t2 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
where t2.register='absent' or t2.register IS NULL;
```

Comment: Smart... This looks copy of mine??

Comment: Yes, was trying queries on sqlfiddle with the link you have provided. It looks cool for quickly trying out queries. Also, I would prefer LEFT JOIN as it would avoid any names that are present in t2 but not in t1.

Comment: sorry, i have restructured my question. i made a mistake in my second table, it was actually the users id from table 1. thank you for your swift responds.